# Finding a set of points for which $y = (x^2-1)^4$ is concave down

Tags: derivatives

Sorry if the formatting is slightly off - this is my first post here.

We are given: $$y = (x^2-1)^4$$

I have found:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 8(x^2-1)^2(7x^2-1)$$

We have to state the set of values of $x$ for which $y = (x^2 - 1)^4$ is concave downwards.

---

I know that the curve is concave down when $d^2y/dx^2 < 0$, however, in the solutions, it writes that it is concave down when $(7x^2-1) < 0$

This leads to answers of $-\frac{1}{\sqrt7} < x < \frac{1}{\sqrt7}$.

Why is this the case? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$ (x^2-1)^2 $
is non-negative for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so the only chance for
$$ y''(x) = 8(x^2-1)^2(7x^2-1) $$
to be negative is if $7x^2-1 < 0$, which you can solve e.g. graphically or by making a sign table.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now. Just was looking at it for too long and didn't see that.

Comment: @MaxO'Brien No problem! Welcome to MSE by the way!